# replacing dishwasher hose, which way do I turn this?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I am trying to replace a hose on my portable dishwasher. The connection is very difficult to reach and I'm not sure what I should be turning and which way I should be turning it. It was very hard to get a good picture but I'm attaching what I got. The hose end has a male screw end and that seems to go into a female socket type thing. Any suggestions for a proper tool and which way to turn? Thanks.[image: dishwasher]
[image: dishwasher hose]

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with anything threaded, the thing to remember is "Righty Tighty, Lefty Loosey"
If you want to remove the hose then you have to get a wrench on it and turn it to the left.
If you want to put the hose on and tighten in you have to turn it to the right.
If its a portable dishwasher you may be able to move it and tilt it in a position that allows you to have better access.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher. The problem is I'm not sure which piece I should be turning. I don't think it would be the hose piece since that is solid, but rather the female piece that's on the back of the dishwasher. If that's correct then am I supposed to turn that piece to the left?

Comment: yes, you want to get your wrench onto that hexagonal part closest to the thread. not the octagonal crimp.  when you turn it the whole hose will turn, so have the other end of the hose loose when you do this.

Comment: Lefty loose right is tight will work for most threaded fittings but not "anything" hazardous , or gas fittings have a gruve in the nut this identifies it as left handed threads or opposite of your answer, most fittings are left loose right tight but not all.

Comment: Jasen, this is what I wanted to know. It seemed to me that there should be something else that turns onto that threaded piece rather than having to turn the whole hose, but this is what we will try. Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: The only part that would turn is the hexagonal part that is just below the crimped hose fitting. Now, there is a possibility that there is a female threaded part that this male part you show screws into and if that is the case you will have to get a wrench on it and hold it secure while you turn the hexagonal part you show above.

Answer (score 1):

The tool to use in that tight spot is a flare-nut wrench (spanner) with an offset end.

[image: Flare-nut wrench]

Hopefully, the hose is small enough to fit through the slot in the wrench socket... but the slot could be filed larger, if need be.